# How to find index of the first unique elements in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

Consider

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame("Name":["Adam","Joseph","James","James","Kevin","Kevin","Kevin","Peter","Peter"])
```

I want to get the index of the unique values in the dataframe.

When I do `df1["Name"].unique()`
I get the output as

```
['Adam','Joseph','James','Kevin','Peter']
```

But I want to get the location of the first occurrence of each value

```
[0,1,2,4,7]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use `numpy.unique` with the `return_index` as True.

```
np.unique(df1, return_index=True)
Out[13]: 
(array(['Adam', 'James', 'Joseph', 'Kevin', 'Peter'], dtype=object),
 array([0, 2, 1, 4, 7], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Sadly, this is much slower.  For my dataframe with 5.6 million elements: `%timeit dfcip["station"].unique()` → 152 ms; `%timeit np.unique(dfcip["station"])` → 2.99 s, nearly a factor 20 slower.

Answer (score 2):

numpy answer is great but here is one workaround :

```
out = df1.reset_index().groupby(['Name'])['index'].min().to_list()
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 7]
```

Comment: Good use of `min` in this case! :D

Comment: Quite a bit slower than `df[col].unique()`, but much faster than `np.unique(df[col])`: for my dataframe with 5.6 million elements, `df[col].unique()` takes 152 ms, whereas the `groupby().min()` approach takes 500 ms.  The numpy approach takes 2.99 s (see comment on that answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code using **RANK**

```
df1['rank'] = df1.groupby(['Name'])['Name'].rank(method='first')
df1[df1['rank'] == 1].index

Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 4, 7], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

First match = first location

```
In[49]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Adam","Joseph","James","James","Kevin","Kevin","Kevin","Peter","Peter"]})
   ...: print ([df1.loc[df1['Name']==i].index[0] for i in df1['Name'].unique()])
   ...: 
[0, 1, 2, 4, 7]
```